# Easiest way to override MongoRepository with Spring Java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

How can I override MongoRepository to use my subclass ?

What I've tried didn't work:

```
@Component
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
    //...

    @Bean
    public MongoRepositoryFactoryBean mongoRepositoryFactoryBean() {
        return new MongoRepositoryFactoryBeanPlus();
    }
}

class MongoRepositoryFactoryPlus extends MongoRepositoryFactory {
    public MongoRepositoryFactoryPlus(MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
        super(mongoOperations);
    }
}

class MongoRepositoryFactoryBeanPlus<T extends Repository<S, ID>, S, ID extends Serializable> extends MongoRepositoryFactoryBean<T, S, ID> {
    @Override
    protected RepositoryFactorySupport getFactoryInstance(MongoOperations operations) {
        return new MongoRepositoryFactoryPlus(operations);
    }
}
```

This fails with NPE during initialization:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryInterfaceAwareBeanPostProcessor.getClassForPropertyValue(RepositoryInterfaceAwareBeanPostProcessor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryInterfaceAwareBeanPostProcessor.predictBeanType(RepositoryInterfaceAwareBeanPostProcessor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1397)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:434)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:404)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:398)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:180)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:156)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
    ... 7 more
```